# Doubts on whether json data or JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, html

I'm beginner on programming. I've studied Stack Overflow and W3schools, and made my little project just for learning and improving.

I have a question, my program is working as it should but the problem is I'm not sure (have doubts) is the json file I made real json or JavaScript object?

One says it is and one says it's not, if it's not real json how to change it into real json because I can't figure it out.

I have three groups inside every group is 4 people and those people are the same in all 3 groups but just different numbers (credits or votes whatever), and I have a json file (I think it is json) named 'values.json'.

Here are codes:

```js
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="values.json"></script>
    <style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
       -webkit-box-sizing
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .oee {
      float:left;
      height: 550px;
      width: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .gauge {
      height: 250px;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
    }
     
    h1 { 
      float:left;  
    }

    body {   
      margin: 100px auto;  
      text-align: center; 
    }

    @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    .gauge {
      width: 30%; 
    }

    .oee{width: 50%;
      margin-left: -132px;
    }
    }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body >
    <h1>people votes</h1>
     <div class="all">
         <div id="ww1" class="oee"></div>
        <div id="ww2" class="gauge" data-value=valuesparsed['Pekka']></div><br>
     <div id="ww3" class="gauge"></div><br>
        <div id="ww4" class="gauge"></div>
      </div>    
      <script src="raphael-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="justgage.js"></script>
      <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        var valuesparsed = JSON.parse(values2)

        var dflt = {
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
       //   donut: true,
          gaugeWidthScale: 1.1,
          counter: true,
          hideInnerShadow: true
        }

        var ww1 = new JustGage({
          id: 'ww1',
          value: valuesparsed['Laura'],
          title: 'Laura ',
          defaults: dflt
        });

        var ww2 = new JustGage({
          id: 'ww2',
          title: 'Pekka',
          defaults: dflt
        });
     
         var ww3 = new JustGage({
          id: 'ww3',
          value: valuesparsed['Jussi'],
          title: 'Jussi',
          defaults: dflt
        });
     
         var ww4 = new JustGage({
          id: 'ww4',
          value: valuesparsed['Kalle'],
          title: 'Kalle',
          defaults: dflt
        });

      });
      
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

values.json

```js
    values1= '{"Laura" : 45, "Pekka" : 89, "Jussi" : 35, "Kalle" : 25}';
    values2= '{"Laura" : 75, "Pekka" : 59, "Jussi" : 85, "Kalle" : 95}';
    values3= '{"Laura" : 55, "Pekka" : 15, "Jussi" : 45, "Kalle" : 67}';
```

Comment: at first sight i think your .json content is in a bad format, use [this tool](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to check what's wrong and fix the formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you call values.json is not JSON, but a script in the JavaScript language. Such a script you can indeed include and run via the `script` tag.

If however you want to have JSON format for your data, and you want to have it loaded from a file into your other JavaScript code, then proceed like this:

1. Put JSON in your file (no variable names, no assignments, no trailing semi-colon, just JSON) -- it can only be *one* data structure, so let's use an array:

   ```
   [{"Laura" : 45, "Pekka" : 89, "Jussi" : 35, "Kalle" : 25},
    {"Laura" : 75, "Pekka" : 59, "Jussi" : 85, "Kalle" : 95},
    {"Laura" : 55, "Pekka" : 15, "Jussi" : 45, "Kalle" : 67}]
   ```
2. Remove the `script src=` tag.
3. Mark the DOMContentLoaded callback function as asynchronous:

   ```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function(event) {
   //                                            ^^^^^
   ```
4. Add code within that callback to load and parse the JSON into a variable `arr`:

   ```
   var response = await fetch("values.json");
   var arr = await response.json();
   var valuesparsed = arr[1]; // choose here which of the three you want to work with

   // Rest of your code comes here...
   ```

Comment: thanks for right answer, i have one question, why you didnt use JSON.parse(), for parsing ? are there many ways of 'parsing' ?

Comment: I didn't use it, because a `fetch` response provides a method to do that. Otherwise you would have to first retrieve the text from the response with `await response.text()` and *then* call `JSON.parse` on it, which represents one step more.

Comment: can i ask why you used fetch and not ajax, or is it not needed ?

Comment: Fetch is doing ajax. Maybe you are thinking of jQuery's implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Your value.json

```
values1= '{"Laura" : 45, "Pekka" : 89, "Jussi" : 35, "Kalle" : 25}';
values2= '{"Laura" : 75, "Pekka" : 59, "Jussi" : 85, "Kalle" : 95}';
values3= '{"Laura" : 55, "Pekka" : 15, "Jussi" : 45, "Kalle" : 67}';
```

is not really JSON.

JSON starts with either

> {

An object.

or

> [

An Array.

and ends with the same depending on their start.

An examaple would be

```
{"Laura" : 45, "Pekka" : 89, "Jussi" : 35, "Kalle" : 25}
```

In Your scenario you would like to have a JSON array that will hold your objects, something like this:

```
[{
        "Laura": 45,
        "Pekka": 89,
        "Jussi": 35,
        "Kalle": 25
    },
    {
        "Laura": 75,
        "Pekka": 59,
        "Jussi": 85,
        "Kalle": 95
    },
    {
        "Laura": 55,
        "Pekka": 15,
        "Jussi": 45,
        "Kalle": 67
    }
]
```

Comment: first i did it like this but didnt know how to connect each group to each people, got one working and another didnt ...

Comment: `0`, `"Hello"`, `null` are all valid JSON representations, in addition to objects and arrays.

Comment: how to make it work like it is now but with real json ?

Answer (score 0):

The content of `values.json` is a JavaScript program which assigns three string literals to three global variables.

The *value* of each of those strings is a JSON text.

If you wanted to have *just* JSON in that file, then you would need either:

*3 separate URLs* each containing a JSON text like:

```
{"Laura" : 45, "Pekka" : 89, "Jussi" : 35, "Kalle" : 25}
```

or *1 URL containing an array of objects*:

```
[
  {"Laura" : 45, "Pekka" : 89, "Jussi" : 35, "Kalle" : 25},
  {"Laura" : 75, "Pekka" : 59, "Jussi" : 85, "Kalle" : 95},
  {"Laura" : 55, "Pekka" : 15, "Jussi" : 45, "Kalle" : 67}
]
```

**Then** you would need to load the JSON data using a different mechanism (it JSON is not JavaScript, you cannot load it using `<script>`) such as [the fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
async function process_json() {

    const response = await fetch('your_json.json');
    const data = response.json();
    console.log(data);

}
```

Comment: as it is now working, but how to make it work with real json ?

Comment: and for selexting json text i need some kind of looping ? could you give and example of that also, or it could be done without loop ?

Answer (score 0):

So, @walee, just to emphasise on the existing answers, I've created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vC0wnbb8IQDJBsvskZDp?p=preview) to sort of show [the difference between JSON and JS objects](https://medium.com/techtrument/javascript-object-vs-json-117965ea3dea).

In a nutshell, I've extracted your values.json to real json:-

```
[
    {"Laura" : 45, "Pekka" : 89, "Jussi" : 35, "Kalle" : 25}
    ...
    ...
]
```

And Js:

```
const values1 = {"Laura": 45, "Pekka": 89, "Jussi": 35, "Kalle": 25},
    ...
```

In the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vC0wnbb8IQDJBsvskZDp?p=preview), I've demonstrated fetching the json file using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), but fill free to use any HTTP library out there.

Comment: now it is working and doesnt need any loops, but when using json array do i need some kind of looping through it ? in order to  parse values ?

Comment: Not really, you don't always need loops. You can still access array elements via keys e.g arrayValues[0] to get the first object and arrayValues[n-1] for the last object (where n is the length of your array)

Comment: The plunker does not correctly show how to process the values from the JSON file. The code runs correctly only because you also define the values *inside* the script. But once you take that out and only rely on the JSON, it doesn't work.

Comment: @trincot, how are script defined variables related to JSON buddy?